# change ellipse color in row

Tags: loops, colors, ellipse

I am trying to make a grid of ellipses, with each row a different color. As the row goes along the color needs to gradually get paler until the final column is white

This is my code:

```
void setup ()
{
  size (1180,680);
  background (0);
  noFill ();
  noStroke ();
}

void draw () {



  fill (150,25,25);                
  for (int x = 100; x < 1100; x = x+120) {
    for (int y = 100; y < 200; y = y+100) {
      ellipse (x,y,100,100); 
   }
  }


  fill (25,150,25);                       
  for (int x = 100; x < 1100; x = x+120) {
    for (int j = 220; j < 250; j = j+100){
      ellipse (x,j,100,100);
    }
  }

  fill (25, 25, 150);             
  for (int x = 100; x < 1100; x = x+120) {
    for (int w = 340; w < 350; w = w+100){
      ellipse (x,w,100,100);
    }
  }  

  fill (255, 204, 25);                  
  for (int x = 100; x < 1100; x = x+120) {
    for (int n = 460; n < 470; n = n+100){
      ellipse (x,n,100,100);
    }
  }

  fill (204, 25, 255);
  for (int x = 100; x < 1100; x = x+120) {
    for (int k = 580; k < 590; k = k+100){
        ellipse (x,k,100,100);
    }
    }
  }
```

I am unsure if this is the correct way to get the grid this way with changing colors. Is there a type of loop that will change each subsequent ellipse color in a row? How should I get a gradual color drain along the row?

Comment: Which language is this? Which API are you using? How/where do you paint?

Comment: This is using Processing2

Comment: Anything helpful would be appreciated